# Why does Java integer act erroneously at values near 2^31-1?

Tags: java, integer

I'm trying to write a Java program to calculate the square root of an integer x, without using in-built functions like `Math.pow()` . This is the approach I tried -

```
class Solution {
    public int mySqrt(int x) {
        
        if(x==0 || x==1)
            return x;
        
        // if(x>=2147395600)
        //     return 46340;
        
        int i;
        for(i=1 ; i*i<=x ; i++) {}
        return i-1;
        
    }
}
```

Without the commented part, I start getting errors if x is in the range 2147395600 <= x <= 2^31-1 (which is the upper limit of an int's value range in Java). For instance, for the input x=2147395600, the expected output is 46340 but the actual output is 289398. Why is this happening? Thanks to all in advance.

PS - I am aware there are other (better) methods to solve this problem, but I'd really like to know why this code behaves this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 46340 * 46340 = 2147395600, when `i=46340, x=2147395600` and you reach the condition `i*i<=x` it evaluates to `true` since 2147395600 = 2147395600. So the loop counter will incremnet by 1 and in the next iteration we will get `i=46341` and `i * i` will cause an overflow - 46341*46341 = -2147479015.
The loop condition will still be `true`, since -2147479015 <= 2147395600, and the loop will not stop.
You can replace the `<=` with `=`, and check for edge cases that may occur now.